# Eclipse, mac os x pydev django environment variables

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I am using django framework inside my virtual env. In terminal window i am setting environment variables. But when i runserver via eclipse env variables can not be recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the environment variables in Eclipse or modify `manage.py` so they get set within the code. I would recommend the former, the latter can be done like so:

```
import os
os.environ['HEMMINGWAY'] = 'Anyone can be a fisherman in May.'
```

In Eclipse you should look for something like this to set environment variables:
[image: Eclipse PyDev environment variable settings]

Comment: and i think i have to hide secure info in environment variables. When deploying to production server setting env vars depends on that server, is it true?

Comment: Yes, environment variables can be set in many different places. Learn about your production environment to find the most secure place to set them.